# Heroku and Rails: transferring db to staging and db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I've been working on a Heroku app for several months.  We've recently set up a staging server and occasionally [sync the staging db with the production db](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#transfers).  The three main commands in use are:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture --app myapp

$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE --app myapp-staging --confirm myapp-staging"

$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp` --app myapp-staging
```

The problem is that after running the third command, I need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate --app myapp-staging`.  We have a few dozen migrations now, including some that refer to Ruby classes that we've deleted or renamed.

This causes the migrations to fail to fully run.  What's the solution here?  Should I delete the old migrations that fail and commit these changes to the git repo?

Comment: Why do you need to run migrations - the code and the data should be the same once you've done this.

Comment: @NeilMiddleton I updated my question--I believe the pg:reset command is what resets the schema.  We're trying to streamline this process into a rake task that our designers can run.  The second command is necessary because we're not assuming that all migrations are pushed to staging and production and run simultaneously--it's possible that we might test out migrations on staging, or someone might push to production without pushing to staging first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-running this script fixed the error, so it seems like the schema should just copy over.  For anyone seeing a failing migration like I did, the `pgbackups:restore` command probably failed for you, so re-run that.

Comment: I should add that I tried re-running the script before posting this question and there weren't any errors that caught my eye.

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout the transfer command now as part of pgbackups .. see this post

[How do I transfer production database to staging on Heroku using pgbackups? Getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673630/how-do-i-transfer-production-database-to-staging-on-heroku-using-pgbackups-gett)